# Use of Amazon Lambda to inform a user via SNS about a change in the DynamoDB

Tags: android, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

Currently I am trying to build some kind of messaging service with AWS as backgroundservice. However I am struggling, because I never used Javascript so far.

The basic idea is: if there is a change in the DynamoDB, notify the "Creator" about the change via a push message.

The weird thing is, that when I hit "Test" it works out just fine, however when I modify the database directly nothing happens. The even weirder thing is, once or twice a day I get a notification when I change it in the database. So it all seems kind of random and I hope someone can help me out.

This is the code that runs on lambda

```
console.log('Loading function');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();
var async = require('async');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {


    var target = null;
    var status = null;

    async.waterfall([
            event.Records.forEach(function(record){

                console.log("Function Invoked");

                if(record.eventName == "MODIFY" && record.dynamodb.NewImage.creator.S!=record.dynamodb.NewImage.participant.S){

                    console.log("If-Cause entred!");

                    var creator = record.dynamodb.NewImage.creator.S;
                    var participant = record.dynamodb.NewImage.participant.S;


                    creator = JSON.stringify(creator);
                    status = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.status.S);
                    creator = creator.replace(/"/g, "");
                    status = status.replace(/"/g, "");

                    participant = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.participant.S);
                    participant = participant.replace(/"/g, "");



                    console.log("creator: "+ creator);
                    console.log("status: "+ status);

                    console.log("participant: "+ participant);


                    getArn(creator,function(response){
                        console.log("RESPONSE: "+ response);

                        //  var name_part = null;

                        //   getName(participant,function(response){
                        //     name_part = response;
                        //    });

                        var sns = new aws.SNS();
                        var payload_accepted = {
                            "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Your event has been accepted!!\"} }"
                        };

                        var payload_declined = { "GCM": "{ \"data\":  { \"message\": \"Your event has been declined!\" } }" };

                        //  payload_declined.GCM.data.message = "Hello";



                        payload_accepted = JSON.stringify(payload_accepted);
                        payload_declined = JSON.stringify(payload_declined);

                        var payload;

                        if(status == "true"){
                            payload = payload_accepted;
                        }else{
                            payload = payload_declined
                        }


                        var params = {
                            TargetArn: response,
                            MessageStructure: 'json',
                            Message: payload
                        };

                        sns.publish(
                            params, function(err, data) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.log(err.stack);

// Notify Lambda that we are finished, but with errors
                                    context.done(err, 'Brians Function Finished with Errors!');
                                    return;
                                }
                                console.log('push sent');
                                console.log(data);

// Notify Lambda that we are finished
                                context.done(null, 'Brians Function Finished!');
                            });



                    });
                }





            })
        ],
        function (err) {

            context.done(null, 'Brians Function Finished!');

            //this last function runs anytime any callback has an error, or if no error
            // then when the last function in the array above invokes callback.
            if (err) { sendForTheCodeDoctor(); }
        });
};


function getArn(userid, callback) {



    var params = {

        TableName : "users",
        Key : {
            "id" : userid
        },

        ProjectionExpression: 'arn'

    }

    dynamo.getItem(params, function(err, data) {


        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return err;
        }
        else {
            console.log(data.Item.arn);
            var response = data.Item.arn;

            return callback(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 0):

You have a race condition stemming from how you are using `async.waterfall`. What you want is `async.each` or something similar (I'd advise having a look at what each available function does in [the docs](https://github.com/caolan/async#collections)).

At the moment your code will synchronously run the `event.Records.forEach` function immediately, each iteration will asynchronously try to send an SNS message but as soon as the `forEach` completes (which is likely to be before your SNS message is sent) `async.waterfall` callback will be called and the `context.done` function invoked. At this point the execution ends. Even if the SNS does complete before your callback is called, it itself will call `context.done`, preventing the next iteration from sending an SNS.

You want something more like this:

```
async.each(event.Records,function(record,done){
  //extract information etc
  sns.publish(params,done);
}, function(err){
  context.done(err);
});
```

This way `context.done` is only called once and after all SNS messages have been sent

Comment: Actually "context.done" always has to be called. If not, you will get some wierd problems with Lambda sooner or later.

Comment: That is true. But your code was calling it multiple times which was the issue I was pointing out. Your updated code will have the same issue if you try to handle more than one event with the same lambda invocation.

Comment: would you please correct the "Updated" Code and post it here? Because somehow Lambda is still acting a bit wierd. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I figured out that the IF-Condition in the very beginning is causing troubles. The following code works just fine and might be helping others, who want to do the same thing as I did.

This Lambda function gets automatically invoked if there happens a change in the DynamoDB. It then checks what kind of change happened, and informs the creator of the DynamoDB entry via Push ( SNS ).  It even provides a customizable Message that gets send. Just put the String you want to be transmitted.

Its basically the core piece of a Messaging Service like Whatsapp.

```
console.log('Loading function');
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var doc = require('dynamodb-doc');
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = function(event, context) {    


    var target = null;
    var status = null;


    event.Records.forEach(function(record){

        console.log("Function Invoked");
        console.log("Function Event: "+record.eventName);


        if (record.eventName == "MODIFY") db_record_exists(record, function(r) {
          if (r) {

             if(r.handle == "true"){
                creator = r.creator;
                participant = r.participant;

                creator = JSON.stringify(creator);
                status = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.status.S);
                creator = creator.replace(/"/g, "");
                status = status.replace(/"/g, "");

                participant = JSON.stringify(record.dynamodb.NewImage.participant.S);
                participant = participant.replace(/"/g, "");

                console.log("creator: "+ creator);
                console.log("status: "+ status);
                console.log("participant is: "+ participant);    

                getCredentials(creator,participant,function(response){
                console.log("RESPONSE: "+ response);

                sendSNS(response, status, context);    

                }); 

              }else{
                  shutdown(context);
              }
          } else shutdown(context);
        }); 
    }
  );
};



function db_record_exists(record, callback){

        var users = {};
        users.creator = record.dynamodb.NewImage.creator.S;
        users.participant = record.dynamodb.NewImage.participant.S;

        if(users.creator != users.participant){
            users.handle = "true";
        }else{
            users.handle = "false";
        }

        callback(users);
} 

function shutdown(context){
        context.done();
}


function sendSNS(creator_information, status, context){

        var sns = new aws.SNS();
        var payload_negative = creator_information.name + " has declined your event!";
        var payload_positive = creator_information.name + " has accepted your event!";
       //var payload_positive = "Positive";

        var payload_accepted = {
                        "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"Your event has been accepted!!\"} }"
                        };

        var payload_declined = { "GCM": "{ \"data\":  { \"message\": \"Your event has been declined!\" } }" };

     //   console.log("Standart Message as JSON: "+ payload_declined.GCM);

        payload_declined.GCM = "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \""+payload_negative+"\" } }";
        payload_accepted.GCM = "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \""+payload_positive+"\" } }";


     //   console.log("Standart Message as JSON: "+ payload_declined.GCM);
      //  console.log("Standart Message as String: "+ JSON.stringify(payload_declined));


        payload_accepted = JSON.stringify(payload_accepted);
        payload_declined = JSON.stringify(payload_declined);

        var payload;

        if(status == "true"){
            payload = payload_accepted;
        }else{
            payload = payload_declined;
        }


        var params = {
        TargetArn: creator_information.arn,
        MessageStructure: 'json',
        Message: payload
        };

        sns.publish(
           params, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);

// Notify Lambda that we are finished, but with errors
            context.done(err, 'Brians Function Finished with Errors!');  
            return;
        }
        console.log('push sent');
        console.log(data);

// Notify Lambda that we are finished
        context.done(null, 'Brians Function Finished!');  
    });
} 

function getCredentials(creator,participant,callback) {

    var params_name = {

    TableName : "users",
    Key : {
        "id" : participant
    },

    ProjectionExpression: 'person_name'

}
    var params_arn = {

    TableName : "users",
    Key : {
        "id" : creator
    },

    ProjectionExpression: 'arn'

}

    dynamo.getItem(params_name, function(err, data) {

     var response = {};

            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return err;
            }
            else {
                console.log("creators name is: "+data.Item.person_name);
                 response.name = data.Item.person_name;
                 dynamo.getItem(params_arn, function(err, data) {


                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            return err;
                        }
                        else {
                          console.log(data.Item.arn);

                       response.arn = data.Item.arn;

                            return callback(response);
                        }
                 });


            }
    });

}
```